# How to format datarow content for a put request

Tags: c#, http

I need to send a stream of data coming from a datatable as a series of records in this format:

```
"{""firstName"":""Billy Lee"",""lastName"":""Presley"", ... }"
```

is there a simple way to convert the contents of a datatable or datarow into this format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public string DataRowToJSON(System.Data.DataRow row)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> Fields = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn item in row.Table.Columns) Fields.Add(string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", item.ColumnName, row[item].ToString()));
        return string.Format("{{{0}}}", string.Join(",", Fields));
    }
```

I am not completly understand how many quotes you need in result string...

Comment: Thanks I'll try it in the morning (just after 5pm here)